# Эмуляция нажатия на ссылку при проверке request

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы при проверке $_REQUEST["show"] как будто бы была нажата ссылка

```
<a id="calc" href="#calciv"></a>
```

?

Comment: Поточнее опишите задачу, и желательно код покажите

Comment: обновил задачу

Comment: Научитесь выражать свои мысли. Незнаю как кому, но после обновления задачи я все равно не понимаю что вам надо. Напишите: есть код (html), есть код (JS), нажимаем туда-то, происходит то-то, а как сделать чтобы....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_REQUEST не всегда оправдано, а вообще смотрите в сторону ajax, как на родном javascript так и на jQuery.
Ссыль по теме - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ и http://javascript.ru/ajax

Comment: Вот сейчас оно надо очень.